# Finding the probability of a string occurring confusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

The following problem comes from Carol Ash's *The Probability Tutoring Book*

We are asked to find the probability that a $7$ character string contains $1$ vowel, $4$ consonants, and $2$ digits.

My approach:

Combination of vowels: $_{5}C_1$

Combination of consonants: $_{21}C_4$

Combination of digits: $_{10}C_2$

Total $7$ character strings: $_{36}C_7$

So the probability should be $\frac{{_{5}C_1} \times {_{21}C_4} \times {_{10}C_2}}{{_{36}C_7}}$

However this is **wrong** because the string "12ABCDF" is different from "FDCBA21". We need to account for this by multiplying by the ways we can permute the strings: $7!$ right?

However, don't we need to do this for both of total number of $7$-character strings and the number of strings that match the ones we're looking for?

Essentially, we'd be multiplying **both** the numerator and denominator by $7!$ which changes nothing... right?

The answer in the book is telling me $\frac{{_{5}C_1} \times {_{21}C_4} \times {_{10}C_2}}{{_{36}C_7}} \times 7!$. Where is the flaw in my logic/understanding?

Comment: Do you mean to write Combination of digits is $\binom{10}{2}$?

Comment: Of course you have to multiply by $7!$ in the denominator too. You are correct.

Comment: @MathLover so the correct answer is what I had originally $\frac{{_{5}C_1} \times {_{21}C_4} \times {_{10}C_2}}{{_{36}C_7}}$ ?

Comment: Yes. At the same time, this answer is based on the sample space of strings where characters don't repeat. The question should have stated it more clearly.

Comment: @MathLover So the sample space treats the string "12ABCDF" the same as "FDCBA21"?